# Screenshot preview freezes a game for a few seconds

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I have a screenshot preview at the end of the level, but when I show it my game freezes for a bit(low fps for a few seconds). This is code I use to load screenshot and crop it(for a little preview sample). Please, help me to solve this lag issue

```
private IEnumerator ShowScreeshotPreview()
{
    yield return 0;

    screenshotTexture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
    byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(destination);
    yield return 0;

    screenshotTexture.LoadImage(fileData);
    yield return 0;

    Rect croppedSpriteRect = new Rect();
    croppedSpriteRect.height = screenshotTexture.height;
    croppedSpriteRect.width = screenshotTexture.height;
    croppedSpriteRect.y = 0;
    croppedSpriteRect.x = 0;

    croppedTexture = new Texture2D((int)croppedSpriteRect.width, (int)croppedSpriteRect.height);
    yield return 0;

    croppedTexture.SetPixels(screenshotTexture.GetPixels((int)croppedSpriteRect.x, (int)croppedSpriteRect.y, (int)croppedSpriteRect.width, (int)croppedSpriteRect.height));
    yield return 0;

    croppedTexture.Apply(); // Memory leak occurs here
    yield return 0;

    screenshotPrview.mainTexture = croppedTexture;
    yield return 0;

    ScreenshotPreviewAnimator.SetBool("visible", true);
    screenshotLoaded = true;
}
```

Comment: Get/SetPixels are mainly used for copying data from GPU memory over to the CPU side and back. If you just want to blit one texture to another, you can keep this entirely GPU-side and save an expensive round trip across the bus.

Comment: I can't see a reason for this to be an IEnumerator and why are there `yield return 0;`s everywhere?  Each one of those tells the coroutine to wait a frame so you're waiting seven frames on a function that shouldn't take a fraction of one.

Comment: @GuntherFox without yields game freezes for a second. IEnumerable because of corouting.

Comment: What data type is `screenshotPrview`?  Also can we see how this coroutine is called?  And is it intentional that the cropped rectangle's `width` is set to the screenshot's `height`?